# Strange Server-Side Caching issue with Local Development Setup

Tags: php, macos, google-chrome, phpstorm, mamp

I've been experiencing an odd issue where something is getting cached somewhere and I'm not sure which item to blame and it's not only driving me nuts, but slows down my development workflow (and is VERY confusing).

**The Problem:** I save changes made to a PHP file and refresh my browser, however the changes do not show up.
**Expected Behavior:**  The refreshed browser shows the updated file.
**Actual Behavior:** The most recent changes do not show up.

For some background, here are the possible factors that could be contributing to this problem:

- Macbook Pro (16-inch, 2019, 2.6 GHz 6-Core Intel Core i7)
- Mac OS (Monterey v12.5)
- Chrome (v104.0.5112.79)
- MAMP Pro (6.6 Build 33836), Apache (2.4.46), PHP (7.4.21), MySQL (5.7.34)
- Xdebug
- PhpStorm (2022.2 Build #PS-222.3345.135)
- Gulp (v4.0.2) - Unlikely
- BrowserSync (v2.26.14) - Unlikely

I work with WordPress although I don't think that's a factor here. Basically what is happening is I'll go to make a change to a PHP file, which could be just adding more code, fixing an error, or maybe even doing a `var_dump`, and when BrowserSync refreshes, the changes are not reflected, so the new code does nothing, or the error still exists, or the `var_dump` doesn't show up. Another example is once `var_dump` does work, if I go to remove that debugging line, it will still show up.

I haven't figured out a fix either, other than just repeatedly refreshing the browser or re-saving the file (sometimes after adding a few blank lines to "trick" whatever it is causing it to think the file has not been changed). This can happen with or without running Gulp/BrowserSync, but I don't want to rule this out as a potential part of the problem. It's behaving like the file has not been saved.

I sometimes will quit `gulp` and restart to see if that resolves the issue, although it's hard to tell if it has any effect since the problem persists for *maybe* 30 seconds and then I'm able to see the updated file.

This is something that has recently started to happen but doesn't happen consistently. Sometimes everything works as expected, but it's hard to tell what factors are contributing to when the issue starts happening again. Most recently it started again after I restarted PhpStorm (to apply an update).

Has anyone else experienced something like this? I'm not even sure what other information would be helpful, but would be happy to post more details if I'm missing something. Thanks!

Comment: I know this effect from active opcode caching, is this active for some reason?

Comment: @OnkiHara Brilliant! I think that did it. I noticed in MAMP > PHP > Cache module is set to "OPcache", I changed this to "off", restarted Services, and it doesn't appear to be happening anymore!
Any ideas why this happens randomly?
Any ideas how to leave this setting enabled, but keep this issue from happening?

Comment: You should deactivate opcaching in developement - the function caches the compiled version of your scripts and replaces the cache content not on every change, but "randomly" - I am not aware of the exact curcumstances that causes a cache refresh.

Comment: @OnkiHara Perfect! Thanks for the additional details!